# cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'watchQuery') at useQuery

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, graphql, apollo-client

I have a next.js application and when I perform a useQuery I get the error "cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'watchQuery') at useQuery". I have had to change some dependencies to resolve an error rendering my hooks so I had changed my `next` version a few times as well as my `apollo-client` as well I have a feeling it is a dependency related issue here are all my relevant files:
my package.json

```
"dependencies": {
   "@apollo/client": "3.6.2",
   "@apollo/link-error": "^2.0.0-beta.3",
   "@apollo/react-ssr": "^4.0.0",
   "@keystone-6/document-renderer": "^1.1.2",
   "@sentry/nextjs": "^7.52.1",
   "@stripe/react-stripe-js": "^1.1.2",
   "@stripe/stripe-js": "^1.11.0",
   "apollo-upload-client": "^14.1.3",
   "babel-core": "^7.0.0-bridge.0",
   "babel-plugin-macros": "^3.1.0",
   "babel-plugin-styled-components": "^2.1.1",
   "date-fns": "^2.16.1",
   "downshift": "^6.0.12",
   "enzyme": "^3.11.0",
   "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.15.5",
   "graphql": "15.8.0",
   "graphql-tag": "^2.11.0",
   "graphql-upload": "^11.0.0",
   "lodash.debounce": "^4.0.8",
   "next": "^12.2.2",
   "next-with-apollo": "^5.1.1",
   "nprogress": "^0.2.0",
   "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
   "react": "^17.0.2",
   "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
   "react-is": "^17.0.2",
   "react-transition-group": "^4.4.1",
   "styled-components": "^5.2.1",
   "vercel": "^29.3.4",
   "waait": "^1.0.5"
 },
 "devDependencies": {
   "@apollo/react-testing": "^4.0.0",
   "@babel/core": "^7.12.10",
   "@babel/preset-env": "^7.12.11",
   "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.8",
   "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.3",
   "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.6.0",
   "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
   "babel-jest": "^26.6.3",
   "babel-plugin-styled-components": "^2.1.1",
   "casual": "^1.6.2",
   "eslint": "^7.17.0",
   "eslint-config-airbnb": "^18.2.1",
   "eslint-config-prettier": "^7.1.0",
   "eslint-config-wesbos": "^1.0.1",
   "eslint-plugin-html": "^6.1.1",
   "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.22.1",
   "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.4.1",
   "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.3.1",
   "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.22.0",
   "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.2.0",
   "jest": "^26.6.3",
   "prettier": "^2.2.1",
   "react-test-renderer": "^17.0.1"
 },
 "engines": {
   "node": "16.x"
 },
 "//": "This is our babel config, I prefer this over a .babelrc file",
 "babel": {
   "env": {
     "development": {
       "presets": [
         "next/babel"
       ],
       "plugins": [
         [
           "babel-plugin-styled-components",
           "macros",
           {
             "ssr": true,
             "displayName": true
           }
         ]
       ]
     },
     "production": {
       "presets": [
         "next/babel"
       ],
       "plugins": [
         [
           "babel-plugin-styled-components",
           "macros",
           {
             "ssr": true,
             "displayName": true
           }
         ]
       ]
     },
     "test": {
       "presets": [
         [
           "next/babel",
           {
             "preset-env": {
               "modules": "commonjs"
             }
           }
         ]
       ],
       "plugins": [
         [
           "babel-plugin-styled-components",
           {
             "ssr": true,
             "displayName": true
           }
         ]
       ]
     }
   }
 }
}
```

my createClient

```
import { ApolloClient, ApolloLink, InMemoryCache } from "@apollo/client";
import { onError } from "@apollo/link-error";
import { createUploadLink } from "apollo-upload-client";
import withApollo from "next-with-apollo";
import { prodEndpoint, cors } from "../config";

function createClient({ headers, initialState }) {
return new ApolloClient({
  link: ApolloLink.from([
    onError(({ graphQLErrors, networkError }) => {
      if (graphQLErrors)
        graphQLErrors.forEach(({ message, locations, path }) =>
          console.log(
            `[GraphQL error]: Message: ${message}, Location: ${locations}, Path: ${path}`
          )
        );
      if (networkError)
        console.log(
          `[Network error]: ${networkError}. Backend is unreachable. Is it running?`
        );
    }),
    createUploadLink({
      uri: prodEndpoint,
      cors,
      fetchOptions: {
        credentials: "include",
      },
      headers,
    }),
  ]),
  cache: new InMemoryCache().restore(initialState || {}),
});
}

export default withApollo(createClient);
```

and my _app.js

```
import { ApolloProvider } from "@apollo/client";
import NProgress from "nprogress";
import Router from "next/router";
import Page from "../components/Page";
import "../components/styles/nprogress.css";
import apolloClient from "../lib/withData";

Router.events.on("routeChangeStart", () => NProgress.start());
Router.events.on("routeChangeComplete", () => NProgress.done());
Router.events.on("routeChangeError", () => NProgress.done());

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  // const router = useRouter();
  return (
    <ApolloProvider client={apolloClient}>
      <Page>
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </Page>
    </ApolloProvider>
  );
}

MyApp.getInitialProps = async function ({ Component, ctx }) {
  let pageProps = {};
  console.log(pageProps);
  if (Component.getInitialProps) {
    console.log(`Paging all props ${pageProps}`);
    pageProps = await Component.getInitialProps(ctx);
  }
  pageProps.query = ctx.query;
  return { pageProps };
};

export default MyApp;
```